# How to process audio in real time?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I have some audio input through microphone. I recorded it in Audacity, it looks something like as shown below.

[image: Audio waveform]

I want to process this audio in real time. I mainly want to do this:

1. See real time audio amplitude vs time graph.
2. Perform some actions based on event like if a wave pattern is seen similar to some predefined wave pattern, then call a function.
   In the upper half part of the image, you can see four disturbances. I want that whenever this disturbance is seen, the script should call a function, otherwise, when the signal is almost straight, do nothing just keep analyzing signal.

Is there any Python module or C library that can allow me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'd Suggest to get yourself introduced to FFT first, that will make you able to do lot of analysis and control over the processing on your audio at realtime.

1# A forward FFT will give you amplitude within the time-domain, converted from your frequency domain (the audio data itself)
2# Based on the amplitude patterns within the time / frequency - you can decide to call extra thread or function; for example - when you get no amplitude on certain frequency bin or timeslot - do something, skip otherwise.

There are a plenty of opensource C libraries to perform FFT on audio data, like http://aubio.org/ or https://github.com/zaphire/Monocle-Engine/blob/master/Core/Audio/fft.cpp there are a lot more. But be sure to make you understand FFT and sound analysis before you proceed. I've personally not used any of these C libraries - instead did a lot with iOS audio analysis, but the working principals should be similar

Comment: Getting FFT has everything to do with the OP question.  FFT is the basis of many algorithms and could be a good starting place for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) has what you're looking for, but it's pretty hard to tell when your target task is "perform some actions based on some thing"

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking voice recognition here, you may have a look at [dragonfly](https://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/) which is described as

> a Python package which offers a high-level object model and allows its
>   users to easily write scripts, macros, and programs which use speech
>   recognition.

or [pyspeech](https://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/)

> speech.py is a Python module that provides a clean interface to
>   Windows's voice recognition and text-to-speech capabilities. It's very
>   easy to use within a program that needs to listen for specific phrases
>   or general speech, or that needs to speak.

Anyway, these two python modules look like processing real time audio, may give you some hints...

Answer (score 0):

For point *1* you can use [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/).

Point *2* is very unspecific *but* you can try your luck with PythonInMusic (after the answer from Mason Hemmel)